# How are the two versions of 別 / 别 used?

Tags: characters

I've noticed that 別 / 别 have two slightly different variations.

Is there any difference in how the respective variations are used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are just variants of the same character.

别 is the one chosen in the standard of China Mainland.

別 is the one chosen in the standards of Hong Kong, Japan, North Korea, South Korea, Taiwan and Vietnam.

Comment: Does that mean the left side doesn't come from 另 historically?

Comment: Yes. The evolution is a bit complex.  別 is evolved from . And 另 is evolved from , and at some point of history, it borrowed left part of 別. Both 別 and 另 in some cases they shared the meaning "separate". More, another similar word 叧, is a variant of 剮.  In the old day, everyone wrote by hand. One might made mistakes or wrote in his own short-hands. Variants and mix-up was quite common in this situation. It is not easy to trace back every character. , , and 剮 have different pronunciation and origin.

Answer (score 1):

PRC's 「别」 represents two different orthodox characters. They are

- 別 (**bié**)
- 彆 (**biè**, colloquial language meaning *to dissuade*)